# Sed append file is possibile use $?

Tags: bash, sed

I have this code:

```
sed -i -e '$a\
persist.sys.timezone=Europe/Rome \
ro.miui.region=IT \
ro.miui.cust_variant=it \
ro.product.locale.language=it \
ro.product.locale.region=IT \
ro.product.mod_device=$DEVICE_NAME_miuita_global \
ro.miui.mcc=9998 \
ro.miui.mnc=9999 \
net.dns2=8.8.4.4' $BUILDPROP'
```

He works perfectly except this string

```
ro.product.mod_device=$DEVICE_NAME_miuita_global
```

that remains without changes

generally $DEVICE_NAME call the device name automatically for example if work on cancro

`ro.product.mod_device=cancro_miuita_global`

I want to point out that in my code bash the function $DEVICE_NAME is perfect so when I use the sed function, I do not see the variable

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: try changing the single quote to double `sed -i -e "$a ......."`

Comment: Sorry double quote not work script

Answer (score 0):

Change $DEVICE_NAME to ${DEVICE_NAME}.

You can omit the curly braces when the variable name is followed by white space (like your $a variable is).

Comment: Thanks, but not working i have use this code sed -i -e '$a ro.product.mod_device=${DEVICE_NAME}_miuita_global' $BUILDPROP but output is ro.product.mod_device=${DEVICE_NAME}_miuita_global

Comment: It would work if you had kept the change from single quote to double quote as suggested by the first commenter

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '$a\
persist.sys.timezone=Europe/Rome \
ro.miui.region=IT \
ro.miui.cust_variant=it \
ro.product.locale.language=it \
ro.product.locale.region=IT \
ro.product.mod_device='"$DEVICE_NAME"'_miuita_global \
ro.miui.mcc=9998 \
ro.miui.mnc=9999 \
net.dns2=8.8.4.4' $BUILDPROP
```

You need to punch-a-hole through to the shell, first by closing the existing command (closing single quote), then surround the variable (to cater for spaces) with double quotes and finally re-open the command again.